# Limit of power of an integral $\lim_{t \to 0} (\int_{0}^{1}(1+x)^{t} dx)^{1/t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Limit of power of an integral

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \left(\int_{0}^{1}(1+x)^{t}dx\right)^{1/t}$$

First i noted inner integral goes to $0$, so I write $I$ in place of inner integral:

$$\lim_{t \to 0}  \left(1+ I-1\right)^{\frac{1}{t} \cdot \frac{I-1}{I-1}} = \lim_{t \to 0} \exp\left(\frac{I-1}{t}\right)$$

Thus we have 
$$ \exp \left(\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{1} (1+x)^t dx - \int_{0}^{1} (1+x)^0 dx}{t}\right) \\
 = \exp \left(\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{1} (1+x)^t dx\right) \\
 = \exp \left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (1+x)^t dx\right) \\
 =  \exp \left(\int_{0}^{1} (1+x)^t \ln(1+x) dx\right)$$

Where I just let $(1+x)^{t} = 1$ as $t\to 0$ (might not be justified, so *may be incorrect*)

Then on integration I get

$$\exp \left((x+1) \ln(1+x)-x \rvert^{1}_{0}\right) = \exp(2\ln(2)-1) = \color{green}{\boxed {\frac{4}{e}}}$$

**Q** Now I do not understand *if this process is correct*. And can we *avoid Leibniz Rule* in this question?

**Also** how can I check *whether this answer is correct*?

Thanks a lot for devotion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculating the inner integral we get
$$\frac{\left(-1+2^{t+1}\right)t}{1+t}$$ and now you can calculate the limit

Comment: Sonnhardo,  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B(1%2Bx)%5Et,%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D  ???

Comment: no it is not, and my Name is Sonnhard

Comment: Totally missed this, thanks :). And tired is pointing out your typo, it should be $2^{t+1}-1 ...$